# Unity's Microphone not playing any sound back

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the microphone to work in Unity. I don't get any errors and the code doesn't break, however, I can't hear any output sound from the microphone. The spectrum data that I get from the audio listener (which is attached to the main camera of the scene) doesn't change.

If you guys know where the problem may be please enlighten me :)

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

///<summary>
/// Get the impulse response of a room with the device's microphone, to calculate the convolution reverb
///</summary>
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ImpulseResponse : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool micFound = false;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Start() {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        // Ask for mic access from user before using it
        StartCoroutine(GetMicrophone());
    }

    private void StartRecording() {
        audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[0], true, 10, AudioSettings.outputSampleRate);
        Debug.Log("Started recording");
        audioSource.loop = true;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    private void StopRecording() {
        Debug.Log("Stop recording");
        Microphone.End(Microphone.devices[0]);
    }

    private IEnumerator GetMicrophone() {
        yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone);
        if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone)) {
            micFound = true;
            Debug.Log("Microphones found: ");
            foreach (var device in Microphone.devices) {
                Debug.Log("Name: " + device);
            }

            StartRecording();
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Microphone not found");
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        // spectrum data --> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.GetSpectrumData.html
        float[] spectrum = new float[256];
        AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.Rectangular);
        for (int i = 1; i < spectrum.Length - 1; i++) {
            Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(i - 1, spectrum[i] + 10, 0), new Vector3(i, spectrum[i + 1] + 10, 0), Color.red);
            Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(i - 1, Mathf.Log(spectrum[i - 1]) + 10, 2),
                new Vector3(i, Mathf.Log(spectrum[i]) + 10, 2), Color.cyan);
            Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(Mathf.Log(i - 1), spectrum[i - 1] - 10, 1),
                new Vector3(Mathf.Log(i), spectrum[i] - 10, 1), Color.green);
            Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(Mathf.Log(i - 1), Mathf.Log(spectrum[i - 1]), 3),
                new Vector3(Mathf.Log(i), Mathf.Log(spectrum[i]), 3), Color.blue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that UnityHub does not have the Microphone permission.

Here are the steps to turn it on:

In step 10, you change to this:

1. Restart your Mac and hold down Command-R until the apple logo and progress bar appear. This will boot your Mac into recovery mode.
2. You may see a window asking you to select a language. If so, make your choice and click the arrow button to continue.
3. Select Utilities / Terminal from the menu bar
4. In the terminal window type: csrutil disable …and hit return. You will see a message confirming you have disabled System Integrity Protection. We will re-enable this before we’re done.
5. Select Terminal/Quit Terminal from the menu bar
6. Select Apple Menu/Restart from the menu bar. Log into your Mac when prompted.
7. in Finder, select Go/Utilities from the menu bar
8. Double click “Terminal” in the Utilities folder
9. In terminal, carefully type this: sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db
   …and hit return.
10. At the sqlite prompt, type this:
    INSERT INTO access VALUES('kTCCServiceMicrophone','com.unity3d.unityhub',0,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UNUSED',NULL,0,1541440109);
    …and hit return.
11. At the sqlite prompt, type this: .exit …and hit return. Be sure to include the initial period
12. (.) or the exit command won’t work.
13. Select Terminal/Quit Terminal from the menu bar

That should grant permission for the Ring application to use your microphone. Now we need to re-enable System Integrity Protection. Repeat steps 1-6, except in step 4 type “enable” instead of “disable”. This is an important step, I strongly advise you not to skip it.

You can confirm that this procedure has worked by selecting Apple/System Preferences, then Security & Privacy, then click the Privacy tab and select “Microphone” on the left side of the window.